# Possible to change the url path?

Tags: uri

Wonder how to make http://example.com instead of http://example.com/drupal? I want everything intact without changes.

Searched for an answer on Google, but there seems to not be one.

Comment: Where you want to change url? Please provide more info

Comment: MAy this will happen by copying all data from drupal directory to root and then delete drupal directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow through these steps hope it could help.

1. Just copy all the data from drupal directory located on the server to one level up.
2. Now delete the drupal directory and check the site by running it directly by  http://example.com
3. if it doesn't work, then check in the setting.php and search for the line if defined.

$base_url= "http://example.com/dev";

// Now change this line to

```
 $base_url = "http://example.com";
```

OR the other way you can rewrite the base using .htaccess file located at the root.

Hope it will help you.